# ASP.Net application pool crashes when loading Matlab dll in IIS8

Tags: asp.net, matlab, iis-8

I've seen similar posts but none of the solutions have worked, so I am hoping someone can help me out as I am tearing my hair out.

I have a ASP.Net application that references a dll that is generated by the Matlab .NET builder (deploy tool).  When I run the app in my development environment, or on a Windows 2008 server with IIS7, it works fine, but when I deploy to a Windows 2012 server running IIS8, the app crashes after the class within the dll is initialized.  I can see in the task manager the memory start to increases significantly, and then the thread terminates and restarts, after a few times the app pool is disabled.  I do not believe RAM is the issue, as the server is running 8GB while my dev machine is running 4GB.  The version of Matlab used to generate the dll is 2010a.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.